# Swift alamofire refactoring trying to return status code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have began to refactor my Alamofire api calls to keep them in a seperate file. The only problem is that I dont know how to return the statuscode as well.

Api file:

```
static func getCategories(_ catId: Int, response: @escaping (JSON) -> ()) {
        let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.categories(catId: catId).description
        Alamofire.request(urlString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON{ (responseData) -> Void in

            let cCatData = JSON(responseData.result.value ?? [])
            response(cCatData)

        }
    }
```

Then in my VC:

```
Api.getCategories(catId) { (JSON) -> () in
            self.categories = JSON["catData"]
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

But I need to know if the status code is 200/400/404/422/500 and I dont want to use the .validate() function, I want to pass the status code

Normally if I would have everything in the same file I would get the status code by:

```
Alamofire.request("https://www.something", parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
                        .responseJSON() { response in
                            if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode { 

if statusCode == 200  {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your closure to pass back the status code, then add an `Int?` parameter and pass it back:

```
static func getCategories(_ catId: Int, response: @escaping (JSON, Int?) -> ()) {
    let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.categories(catId: catId).description
    Alamofire.request(urlString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { responseData in
        let cCatData = JSON(responseData.result.value ?? [])
        response(cCatData, responseData.response?.statusCode)
    }
}
```

Or I might use more standard variable/parameter names:

```
static func getCategories(_ catId: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (JSON, Int?) -> ()) {
    let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.categories(catId: catId).description
    Alamofire.request(urlString, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
        let cCatData = JSON(response.result.value ?? [])
        completionHandler(cCatData, response.response?.statusCode)
    }
}
```

Either way, you can then do:

```
Api.getCategories(catId) { json, statusCode in 
    guard statusCode == 200 else {
        print("status code not 200! \(statusCode)")
        return
    }

    // if you got here, the status code must have been 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want is something like this:

```
func returnStatusCode(_ urlPath: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, headers: [String: String]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default, completion: @escaping (_ statusCode: Int, _ responseData: [String: AnyObject]?) -> Void) {

    // you can omit 'encoding:' if you'll set it to default since it will be default by default. \o/
    Alamofire.request(urlPath, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in

        if response.result.isSuccess, let returnObject = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject], let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
            // do something...

            completion(statusCode, returnObject)
        }
    }
}
```

use the callback to handle the status code alone

Comment: So how do I get the status code and data in the other file?

Comment: I have updated my post. please check. this code uses swift 3.0 alamofire 4.0.1

Comment: ahh yes good point... but if it is success it will always fall to code 200. and if error then handle the error code pertaining to that error. that's what I did here... but if you have suggestion I'm willing to hear it. (y)

Comment: okay I've remove the else block, but won't this prevent him from handling the error code in the NSError?

Comment: Sure, he can add whatever error handling he wants, but don't confuse it with http status codes, which are a completely different thing altogether.